# JSON Mootools Array problem

Tags: php, json, mootools

I developed on localhost a system using mootools and Json
I moved it to the production server and it doesn't work
I've developed a really simple model and it produces null too:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bookingSystem/mootools/mootoolsCore.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bookingSystem/mootools/mootoolsMore.js">
    </script>
    <script>
            function json(){
                var weekDays = JSON.encode({
                    apple: 'red',
                    lemon: 'yellow'
                });
                ;
                alert(weekDays);
                var request = new Request.JSON({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'jsonTest.php',
                    data: {
                    weeks: weekDays
                    },
                    onComplete: function(jsonObj){
                        alert("back");
                    }
                }).send();
            }

</script>


</head>
<body>
    <span onmousedown="json()">JSONTEST</span>
</body>
</html>
```

and php is

```
<?php
   var_dump(json_decode($_POST['weeks']));
 ?>
```

It decodes as NULL.

It worked perfectly with arrays on localhost but I can't get the array to work on my live server.  If I don't use an array it works fine. 
Any ideas where I can start to look.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess would that on your server magic quotes are active while on your development machine not. If the POST variable you use contains quotes `json_decode` fails silently and returns `NULL`.

Magic quotes escapes certain characters (`'`, `"` and the binary zero) in all POST, GET and COOKIE variables automatically with an backslash. A simple variable encoded in JSON may not contain one of these characters so it works on the server, too, but this may be not the case if you encode an array.

http://de.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php discusses how to disable magic quotes, even if you have no access to PHP configuration file.

Comment: is there any way around the problem?

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot.  I thought it was turned off.  I did this:

Comment: if (is_array($_POST['weeks'])){
   $mike = stripslashes($_POST['weeks']);
     }else{
   $mike = ($_POST['weeks']);
     }